# php count and search

Tags: php, arrays, search, count

code

```
$array = array($cat2);
print_r(array_count_values($array));

//out
Array ( [YES] => 1 ) Array ( [YES] => 1 ) Array ( [YES] => 1 ) Array ( [YES] => 1 ) Array ( [NO] => 1 ) Array ( [NO] => 1 ) Array ( [YES] => 1 ) Array ( [NO] => 1 ) Array ( [NO] => 1 ) Array ( [YES] => 1 )
```

how many count YES and NO
this my code

```
$YES = array_search('YES', $array);

$NO = array_search('NO', $array);
```

result out YES

```
Array ( [YES] => 1 ) 0 Array ( [YES] => 1 ) 0 Array ( [YES] => 1 ) 0 Array ( [YES] => 1 ) 0 Array ( [NO] => 1 ) Array ( [NO] => 1 ) Array ( [YES] => 1 ) 0 Array ( [NO] => 1 ) Array ( [NO] => 1 ) Array ( [YES] => 1 ) 0
```

result out NO

```
Array ( [YES] => 1 )Array ( [YES] => 1 )Array ( [YES] => 1 )Array ( [YES] => 1 )Array ( [NO] => 1 )Array ( [NO] => 1 )Array ( [YES] => 1 )Array ( [NO] => 1 )Array ( [NO] => 1 )Array ( [YES] => 1 )
```

i have result out

```
YES = 6
NO = 4
```

this php without mysql, please help me......

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($cat2)`

Comment: this : string(3) "YES" string(3) "YES" string(3) "YES" string(3) "YES" string(2) "NO" string(2) "NO" string(3) "YES" string(2) "NO" string(2) "NO" string(3) "YES"

Comment: Are you counting inside a loop ?

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($cat2);` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$array` is an array containing another array (which I assume you want to group), then try this:

```
print_r(array_count_values($array[0]));
```

Comment: iam use and out `Warning: array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array`

Comment: cat2 is `if ($f1x == "1" and $f2x == "2" ){$cat2 = "NO";}else if ($f1x == "2" and $f2x == "2"){$cat2 = "YES";}`

Comment: The rabbit hole gets deeper. Abandon hope all ye who enter.